# What's the difference between SendKeys "{SPACE}" and Sendkeys " "?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

What's the difference between those two Advanced Scripting commands?

```
Sub Main
  SendKeys "{SPACE}"
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Main
  SendKeys " "
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.speechcomputing.com/node/8053:

> Basically, there is no difference. Both do the same thing.